# SharePoint Welcome Page Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, sharepoint-calendar

I have a SharePoint welcome page that leads to new modern team sub sites, kind like a hub or holder for the sub-sites. The welcome page is on an older version it looks like. The heads of the department want the welcome page to display a calendar of the upcoming reoccurring trainings in a calendar view. The problem is the calendar app i have create is compressed and doesn't show details like this: [image]

This is useless. I have tried adding in script editors to fix the row height none of that is working. I have edited the web part and fixed the height but the actual calendar portion does not increase in size. Is there a ways i can make this stupid calendar show relevant details instead of useless blue lines?

My edit page look like this if that helps:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the default behavior when you add a list web part in the welcome page.

A few things you can check:

1. Make sure the calendar is displayed properly in the calendar list.
2. Delete this web part and create a new one in another zone on the welcome page, for example, the body part.
3. Test on a new page with different template like wiki page.
4. Switch to another browser and test again.

In addition, calendar web part is supported on modern pages, you can create a modern site page as the welcome page which is more convenient.

Reference:

[Use the Group calendar web part.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-group-calendar-web-part-eaf3c04d-5699-48cb-8b5e-3caa887d51ce)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. I put the calendar in every zone on the page the picture just shows the last one I tried. I ended up burning the page out of frustration and went to the modern which is working well. Thank you.